# Retrieving redis hash data

Tags: php, hash, redis, predis

my dev environment is the Laravel PHP framework utilising the predis client library.

I am probably overlooking certain aspects, and I am new to Redis however what I think am wanting is the hash data type for storing user information like so:

```
$redis->hmset('users', array('id' : 1, 'username' => 'ali', 'dob' => '29/06/89', 'email' => 'a@a.com'));
```

My question is however with the above is this the correct way of me storing all users with there information in ONE hash so I can retrieve all users together and retrieve an individual user by ID when necessary, as I am in need of displaying all users in a table on the front end, but also need to grab an individual user by there ID on occasion.

If not and I need to store each user in an individual hash like below with there ID as part of the key how do I retrieve all users in one go and ordered?

```
$redis->hmset('users:{id}', array('name' => 'ali', 'dob' => '29/06/89', 'email' => 'a@a.com'));
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done is as you've said, give each users an id and store them in the format `users:{id}`.

Then you'll want to to store all the user id's in a set, or perhaps a sorted set or list if order matters to you, so something like

```
$redis->sadd('users', {user's id});
```

This is psuedo code for storing in a set because I am not sure of the exact formatting of predis.

Then when you want to retrieve all users, you first do `$redis->smembers('users')` to get all the user ids, and then iterate over those id's to retrieve all the user hashes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and when I want to loop over all users and grab there information, I grab the whole users hash with the ids, and then do a  call every iteration for the users information? is a call to redis for EVERY user intense? or trivial with redis.

Comment: Yes you do a call for every user id stored in the set.  I am by no means an expert but I believe this is absolutely okay for Redis.  You can find more info in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701491/save-nested-hash-in-redis-via-a-node-js-app)